# Angular, component subscribed to subject won't receive event

Tags: angular

I have a service that is responsible to create a subjectbehaviour and listening for updates. One more component will trigger an event to the behaviour subject, and the last component subscribes to it and pushes the value to the array. Below my implementation so far.

this is my service

```
private _menuSubject = new BehaviorSubject<MenuList>({
    menu_item_id:null,
    menu_item_category:null,
    menu_item_description:null,
    menu_item_name:null,
    menu_item_price:null
});
menuListObs$: Observable<MenuList> = this._menuSubject.asObservable();
updateMenuArray(item:MenuList):void {
    this._menuSubject.next(item);
}

 getUpdatedMenuArray():Observable<MenuList>{
    return this.menuListObs$;
}
```

the component that sends the message

```
onSubmit(menu){
   this.menu.updateMenuArray(menu);
}
```

and the component that subscribes to the service for an update

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.menu.getUpdatedMenuArray().subscribe((item)=>{
        this.menuList.push(item)
    });
}
```

The problem I face is that in my last component the subscriber is not triggered. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are they both using the same instance? Which providers array have you added the service to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering the event on the behavioursubject `this._menuSubject.next(item);` but listen to the event on a old observable-copy of the subject.

Try making `_menuSubject`public (or return it in a public getter) and subscribe to it directly. You may want to skip the first item, because the first would be the current value.